# fontconfig error - Unable to install anything

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg, fonts

I am posting this query, after applying all the available solutions. I am using Ubuntu 16.

Problem:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
fontconfig
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Whenever I try to install, update or remove anything, there is always an error which causes the whole process to fail

---

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up fontconfig (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fontconfig
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The Basic Problem is listed in the last line of log file i.e.,

```
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto: Bus error (core dumped)
```

Bus Error is something that is causing problem

Output from `/var/log/fontconfig.log`

```
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: caching, new cache contents: 59 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 5 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-cns1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-gb1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan2: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-korea1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto: Bus error (core dumped)
```

I am unable to use my system properly because of this problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge fontconfig-config` lets see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updates fail because of fontconfig after Ubuntu reinstall](http://askubuntu.com/questions/590334/updates-fail-because-of-fontconfig-after-ubuntu-reinstall)

Comment: Same Error. 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fontconfig
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @George All together different sort of errors and outputs

Comment: @George Kindly have a look at

Comment: /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto: Bus error (core dumped)

Comment: Follow the steps [here](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/install/) and let me know if it resolves the problem cause it appears your missing _google noto fonts_. please add for all users

Comment: By default the `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto`  folder contains the fonts installed by the `fonts-noto-cjk` package. Hence reinstalling `fonts-noto-cjk` may be worth a try: `sudo apt install --reinstall fonts-noto-cjk`

Comment: Thanks man! Problem Solved! I was pretty much going to reinstall ubuntu. Thanks again

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I think you solved this and I don't want to no-repro it... is there a proper dupe target or would you care to answer?

Comment: @Zanna: I'm not aware of any duplicate; just posted it as an answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto` folder contains the fonts installed by the `fonts-noto-cjk` package. Hence reinstalling `fonts-noto-cjk` may be worth a try:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall fonts-noto-cjk
```