# fontconfig not configured yet

Tags: 16.04, fonts

I am trying to install the prerequisite packages for Oracle 12c on UBuntu 16-04.

The last command I tried is:

```
sudo dpkg -i libqtgui4_4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb
```

which gives me the following output:

```
(Reading database ... 84098 files and directories currently
installed.) Preparing to unpack
libqtgui4_4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqtgui4:amd64 (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1)
over (4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) ... dpkg: dependency
problems prevent configuration of libqtgui4:amd64:  libqtgui4:amd64
depends on fontconfig; however:   Package fontconfig is not configured
yet.  libqtgui4:amd64 depends on libqt4-declarative (=
4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1); however:   Package
libqt4-declarative:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libqtgui4:amd64 (--install): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
while processing:  libqtgui4:amd64
```

As far as I understood, there is a configuration problem with fontconfig and libqtgui4:amd64.

Can someone tell me how to handle this, please?

Thank you,

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: I have tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but I still have configuration errors, like `dpkg: error processing package fontconfig (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured`

Comment: Did you see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/590334/updates-fail-because-of-fontconfig-after-ubuntu-reinstall ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/) and [Dependency errors prevent all APT commands from running, "Package libappstream-glib8:amd64 is not configured yet"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855359/)